# Special character with Apache and Spring

Tags: spring, apache, web-services, tomcat, authentication

I use the below code where I set credentials for basic https authentication to my server that uses Spring Security. Unfortunately I have problem with special characters like é,ò etc... I receive on server the question mark `?` instead of correct character (both username and password). Someone know how to resolve it?

```
private RestClient(String username, String password) {
        CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credsProvider.setCredentials(
                new AuthScope(null, -1),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).build();
        setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient));
    }

    public static synchronized RestClient getInstance(String username, String password){
        if (instance == null){
            instance = new RestClient(username, password);
            instance.getMessageConverters().add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        }
        return instance;

    }
```

and then I use for example

```
RestClient restClient = RestClient.getInstance(username, password);
            if (queryParams!=null && queryParams.length!=0){
                response = restClient.getForObject(addQueryParam(url, queryParams), Response.class);
            }
```

I've tried even with `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` into server.xml of tomcat but the issue is still present.

***UPDATE*** maybe I have fixed the issue setting the header manually:

```
 private RestClient(String username, String password) {
        String credential = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((username+":"+password).getBytes());
        // create custom http headers for httpclient
        List<BasicHeader> defaultHeaders = Arrays.asList(new BasicHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic "+credential));
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultHeaders(defaultHeaders).build();
        setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient));
    }

    public static synchronized RestClient getInstance(String username, String password){
        if (instance == null){
            instance = new RestClient(username, password);
        }
        return instance;    
    }
```

I'm testing, let you know

Comment: The user name and password would be sent from the client. Thus encoding would happen there. If encoded wrongly at client I suspect it would not make it back to the server in the corect format. Check if the client is also setup to use UTF-8.

Comment: the client is the above code, and other functions, in a Java library (jar) used into Matlab.